# Square Root only if a number (button) is pressed after the square root symbol

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple calculator (I'm new to js) and was having trouble implementing a way to square root something. I have the entire calculator working except the square root function. As you could imagine, what makes this different is that a number should only be square rooted if a number is pressed after the square root symbol.

Here is the code:

```js
"use strict";

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

let equationValues = [];
let operator;
let stringNumber = "";

buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let num = event.target.textContent;
    let answer = document.querySelector(".answer");

    switch (num) {
      case "+":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "X":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "-":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "÷":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "√":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));  //PROBLEM IS HERE*****
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
      case "=":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        stringNumber = "";
        if (operator == '+') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a + b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == '-') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a - b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == 'X') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a * b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == '÷') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a / b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == '√') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a) {return Math.sqrt(a);}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        }
        equationValues.push(parseInt(num));
        console.log(`${answer.value}, ${equationValues}, ${operator}`);
        break;

      case "0":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "1":
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber += num;
        break;
      case "2":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "3":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "4":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "5":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "6":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "7":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "8":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "9":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
    }
  });
});

document.querySelector(".clear").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector(".answer").textContent = "";
  equationValues = [];
  stringNumber = "";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@100;200;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Calculator Expiriment V2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <section class="calc">
      <p class = "instructions"><em>Please press what you want to calculate</em></p>
      <p class="answer"></p>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>7</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>8</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>9</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>÷</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>4</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>5</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>6</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>X</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>1</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>2</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>3</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>-</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>0</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>√</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>=</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>+</strong></button>
    </section>
    <div class = "left">
      <button class="clear" href="#"><strong>C</strong></button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit to explain what should happen when you press square root, for the numbers before and after? does is root the numbers before? or just the 1 number after? do you want it to find the nth root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculator works only for same sign operations. For example:

```
2 + 4 x 5 = 22  // your calculator prints 40
```

In case you wanted it that way and want it to just work for one number entered after `√` can do an *if-else* to check if the last element in `equationValues` is a number. If it isn't you can print something like *Invalid* while if it is a number you can calculate the sqrt and print the value.

```
else if (operator == '√') {
    let answerValue = "";

    if(!isNaN(equationValues[equationValues.length - 1])) {
        answerValue = Math.sqrt(equationValues[equationValues.length - 1]);
    } else {
        answerValue = "Invalid";
    }

    answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
}
```

**Try it below:**

```js
"use strict";

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

let equationValues = [];
let operator;
let stringNumber = "";

buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let num = event.target.textContent;
    let answer = document.querySelector(".answer");

    switch (num) {
      case "+":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "X":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "-":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "÷":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "√":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));  //PROBLEM IS HERE*****
        operator = num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber = "";
        break;
      case "=":
        equationValues.push(parseInt(stringNumber));
        stringNumber = "";
        if (operator == '+') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a + b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == '-') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a - b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == 'X') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a * b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == '÷') {
          let answerValue = equationValues.reduce((function(a, b) {return a / b;}))
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        } else if (operator == '√') {
          let answerValue = "";
          if(!isNaN(equationValues[equationValues.length - 1])) {
            answerValue = Math.sqrt(equationValues[equationValues.length - 1]);
          } else {
            answerValue = "Invalid";
          }
          answer.textContent += ' ' +  "=" + ' ' + answerValue;
        }
        equationValues.push(parseInt(num));
        console.log(`${answer.value}, ${equationValues}, ${operator}`);
        break;

      case "0":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "1":
        answer.textContent += num;
        stringNumber += num;
        break;
      case "2":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "3":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "4":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "5":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "6":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "7":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "8":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
      case "9":
        stringNumber += num;
        answer.textContent += num;
        break;
    }
  });
});

document.querySelector(".clear").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector(".answer").textContent = "";
  equationValues = [];
  stringNumber = "";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@100;200;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Calculator Expiriment V2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <section class="calc">
      <p class = "instructions"><em>Please press what you want to calculate</em></p>
      <p class="answer"></p>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>7</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>8</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>9</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>÷</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>4</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>5</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>6</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>X</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>1</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>2</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>3</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>-</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>0</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>√</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>=</strong></button>
      <button class="btn" href="#"><strong>+</strong></button>
    </section>
    <div class = "left">
      <button class="clear" href="#"><strong>C</strong></button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```